# Linksys SPA901 won't react to ****

Tags: voip, linksys, phone

Uh… I don't know if this is correct stack exchange to ask, but it's the best one I've found.

I have Linksys SPA901. And when I enter ******** (to enter configuration mode) I hear nothing at all. Also I can ping it, but I can't access web interface. Can it be somehow reset without ******** config? Or is there any other possible solution I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Two methods, sorry I haven't tested either and I haven't got any SPA9xx's around to do so.

One method (easiest but I'm not certain if it will work) : SPA942 Recovery Tool http://www.sipura.net/download/rec942.zip The 6ths post here http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/VoIP-Phones/SPA922-Factory-Reset-Procedure-Does-Not-Work/td-p/247166 suggests once it retrieves the profile from the phone it then deletes the previous config.

The next method is harder (again I haven't tested but I'm confident this should work):

The idea is to send a provisioning file to the phone, and use that to change passwords so you should be able to gain full access to the phone.

To do this, we will need the phone, a switch, and we will need means to set up a DHCP server on which we can specify DHCP options, as well as a TFTP server.

My suggestion would be to use any sensible spec pc, and load up an evaluation copy of Server 2008 R2, set the network card with a static ip and install the DHCP service, install Solarwinds TFTP Server (free), then install Wireshark (also free).

On the DHCP server, change option 66 to the ip address of the box with the TFTP server.
For the TFTP server, find the directory you need to place the files to be served (often called tftproot), and create the following file (case is very important for this).

One file called spa901.cfg with the following contents

```
<flat-profile>
[System]
<Enable_Web_Server group="System/System_Configuration">yes</Enable_Web_Server>
<Web_Server_Port group="System/System_Configuration">80</Web_Server_Port>
<Enable_Web_Admin_Access group="System/System_Configuration">yes</Enable_Web_Admin_Access>
<Admin_Passwd group="System/System_Configuration"/>
<User_Password group="System/System_Configuration"/>
</flat-profile>
```

Once this is done, fire up wireshark and plug the phone and switch to the PC and power cycle the phone.

You should then see the phone get a DHCP lease from the server, then pull the file we created via TFTP. If you see filenames not matching up (I believe certain firmwares changed the files the phones look for), then change the filenames as required.

This file only has settings for the webserver and passwords, it ensures the webserver is enabled on port 80, and clears both the user and admin passwords.

Comment: This doesn't (seem to) work. I've set option 66 in my DHCP server (`option tftp-server-name "<ip address>;`) but the locked phone doesn't make a single TFTP request (according to Wireshark).